# Is there a latest way to type let in code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, xcode, ecmascript-6

"let" is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz). "... please someone shuld Provide me details that how to config for this warning..thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are getting this error message in an IDE like sublime text 3. Please clarify this.

Comment: Yes please......

Comment: Add a file named .jshintrc to your project and inside this file type this.

`{ "esversion": 6 }`